# Drag and drop a slider

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, slider

Is there any possible way to drag and drop a slider using jquery.
I am testing an application in custom built test tool which works using custom script.I need something like script to drag the the slider to desired position on the slider bar.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: var ptor = browser,
    driver = browser.driver; 
var slider = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.css("ngrs-handle ngrs-handle-min")); 
ptor.actions().dragAndDrop(slider,{x:1000,y:0}).perform();
ptor.sleep(10000);